# How to keep ExtJs App alive after page refresh

Tags: javascript, cookies, extjs, extjs4, refresh

What is the best way of showing your ExtJs app after a page refresh?

Example: A window at position x,y with some panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `stateId` property and how saving state works in ExtJs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-cfg-stateful